# Laravel 5 Commands - Execute one after other

Tags: laravel, command, queue, laravel-5

I have a `CustomCommand_1` and a `CustomCommand_2`.

Any way to create a pipeline of commands and executing `CustomCommand_2` right after `CustomCommand_1` execution? (without call a command inside the other one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any way to do this, so I came up workaround (tested on laravel `sync` driver).

First, you have to create/adjust base command:

```
namespace App\Commands;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;

abstract class Command {
    use DispatchesCommands;
    /**
     * @var Command[]
     */
    protected $commands = [];

    /**
     * @param Command|Command[] $command
     */
    public function addNextCommand($command) {
        if (is_array($command)) {
            foreach ($command as $item) {
                $this->commands[] = $item;
            }
        } else {
            $this->commands[] = $command;
        }
    }

    public function handlingCommandFinished() {
        if (!$this->commands)
            return;
        $command = array_shift($this->commands);
        $command->addNextCommand($this->commands);
        $this->dispatch($command);
    }
}
```

Every command has to call `$this->handlingCommandFinished();` when they finish execution.

With this, you can chain your commands:

```
$command = new FirstCommand();
$command->addNextCommand(new SecondCommand());
$command->addNextCommand(new ThirdCommand());
$this->dispatch($command);
```

---

**Pipeline**

Instead of calling `handlingCommandFinished` in each command, you can use command pipeline!

In `App\Providers\BusServiceProvider::boot` add:

```
$dispatcher->pipeThrough([
    'App\Commands\Pipeline\ChainCommands'
]);
```

Add create `App\Commands\Pipeline\ChainCommands`:

```
class ChainCommands {
    public function handle(Command $command, $next) {
        $result = $next($command);
        $command->handlingCommandFinished();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post - using Laravel's command pipeline makes it a lot easier :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback to decide when something will or won't run, using when() or skip():

```
$schedule
    ->call('Mailer@BusinessDayMailer')
    ->weekdays()
    ->skip(function(TypeHintedDeciderClass $decider)
    {
        return $decider->isHoliday();
    }
);
```

Referred: [Event Scheduling](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-event-scheduling) and [Commands & Handlers](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-commands-and-handlers)

You can also read how to add commands in queue [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus#queued-commands).
See, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from doing the following?

```
$this->dispatch(new CustomCommand_1);
$this->dispatch(new CustomCommand_2);
// And so on
```

Comment: Because each custom command calls more commands. And i want to execute `CustomCommand_2` after the execution of the `CustomCommand_1` and its subcommands.

Comment: @idknow Surely by adding them to the queue, they’re _queued_ and run in turn?